# Extracting a single row from $A^{-1}B$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I came across a problem while programming. Given the matrices A and B, I need a specific row from the matrix $H=A^{-1}B$, but I don't want to find $A^{-1}$ given the computational cost. I know I can find any column of $H$ with a simple system of equations, but I can't find a similar formula for a row. So, is there a way to find the nth row of matrix H with a simple system of equations? I know that, since $AH=B$ , I can compute H by H=B\A in Matlab, but is there a way to calculate a row without computing $H$ completely.

Thank you!

Comment: If you can compute a columns easily, how about using $ A^{-1}B = (B^T(A^T)^{-1})^T$?

Comment: `u=zeros(size(A,1),1); u(i)=1; (A'\u)'*B` gives you the $i$-th row of $A^{-1}B$.